# Python - issue with name and thumbnail of the uploaded file

Tags: python, file, jira

Im trying to attach file with atlassian jira api using python requests module. Attachment is successful but name of the attachment becomes `file` and thumbnail of the attachment is improper.Below is the screenshot of attachment from jira after successful ticket creation.

[image]

Python code given below. `"Content-type" : "multipart/form-data"` is directly passed from Front-End javascript code. Please note that atlassian documentation mentions that the name of the multipart/form-data parameter that contains the attachments must be file.

```
file = request.files['file']
files = {'file': file.read()}
response = requests.post(JIRA_URL + '/' + path,
                         headers={'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check'},
                         auth=(JIRA_USER, JIRA_PASS),
                         files=files,
                         proxies={'https': PROXY})
```

Answer (score 1):

I use jira-python and then code such as this

```
        with open(localname, 'rb') as fd:
            jira.add_attachment(target_issue, attachment=fd, filename=att_filename)
```

where localname is the local filename, and att_filename is the actual filename you want to see appear in the issue.

Inside the jira-python code there is

```
    url = self._get_url('issue/' + str(issue) + '/attachments')

    fname = filename
    if not fname:
        fname = os.path.basename(attachment.name)

    if 'MultipartEncoder' not in globals():
        method = 'old'
        r = self._session.post(
            url,
            files={
                'file': (fname, attachment, 'application/octet-stream')},
            headers=CaseInsensitiveDict({'content-type': None, 'X-Atlassian-Token': 'nocheck'}))
    else:
        method = 'MultipartEncoder'

        def file_stream():
            return MultipartEncoder(
                fields={
                    'file': (fname, attachment, 'application/octet-stream')})
        m = file_stream()
        r = self._session.post(
            url, data=m, headers=CaseInsensitiveDict({'content-type': m.content_type, 'X-Atlassian-Token': 'nocheck'}), retry_data=file_stream)
```

which is a bit fiddly. I really recommend using jira-python rather than requests directly